# Adding a Configuration at runtime

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-plugin

I'd like to add a configuration within a plugin at runtime and probably also register it at `projectConfigurations`. Is there a possibility to manipulate the state in such a way? I assume this needs to be done in a command, and the solution is buried somewhere deep inside of the `AttributeMap`, but I'm not sure how to approach that beast.

```
def addConfiguration = Command.single( "add-configuration" )( ( state, configuration ) => {
    val extracted = Project extract state
    val c = configurations.apply( configuration )
    // Add c to the state ...
    ???
} )
```

**Background**

I'm working on a [sbt-slick-codegen](https://github.com/Taig/SbtSlickCodegen/tree/61007017138dc8df31ceeaae5c5d5a6c8550f1dd) plugin, which has multi-database support as an essential feature. Now to configure databases in sbt, I took a very simple approach: everything is stuffed into a Map.

```
databases in SlickCodegen ++= Map(
    "default" -> Database(
        Authentication(
            url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db",
            username = Some( "db_user_123" ),
            password = Some( "p@assw0rd" )
        ),
        Driver(
            jdbc = "org.postgresql.Driver",
            slick = slick.driver.PostgresDriver,
            user = Some( "com.example.MySlickProfile" )
        ),
        container = "Tables",
        generator = new SourceCodeGenerator( _ ),
        identifier = Some( "com.example" ),
        excludes = Seq( "play_evolutions" ),
        cache = true
    ),
     "user_db" -> Database( ... )
)
```

Now, this works, but defeats the purpose of *sbt*, is hard to setup, difficult to maintain and update. I'd instead prefer configuration to work like this:

```
container in Database := "MyDefaultName",
url in Database( "backup" ) := "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/database",
cache in Database( "default" ) := false
```

And also this approach is working on the [current development branch](https://github.com/Taig/SbtSlickCodegen/tree/46071f5a415d39c18920e654d05dbfcc6ea7284e), but only for `Database( x )`-configurations that are known at compile time, which leads to the next problem:

On top of that, I'm planning to add a module with *PlayFramework* support. The idea is to have a setting `SettingKey[Seq[Config]]( "configurations" )` that accepts *Typesafe* `Config` instances, reads the *slick* configurations from them and generates appropriate `Database( x )`-configurations. But for this step I am out of ideas.